# No seekbar/scrubber when opening mp3(audio) urls with url_launcher or flutter_webview_plugin

Tags: android, flutter

When i play an mp3 file through the flutter_webview_plugin or launch it in an webview through url_launch i dont get the option to seek a specific time. It works normally with videos but when it's audio the seekbar/scrubber doesn't appear or actually disappears really fast.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXTdZ.png

Answer (score 0):

And if anyone is still wondering.. The native browser on Android doesn't have better support than this so if you need scrubbing you have to use a player.